# How To Add Rectangle Button to Application Bar in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I Want a applicationbar in windows phone 8.1 as application buttons as normal rectangle button

I customized the application bar button style but no use can please help me to how to approach to develop an application bar

Comment: is it windows phone 8.1 winRt or windows phone 8.1 silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ApplicationBar buttons are round by default.

If you want typical rectangular buttons you will have to build a custom bar that will behave the same way.

Comment: Then how default store application has build with two rectangle buttons? Do you mean Microsoft didn't gave an access to that level?

Comment: Microsoft might have built a custom control to do such kind of arrangement,you never know